# How do I write a ts.d file that exports a javascript object instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a js file that I would like to generate typings for. 
The js exports an object:

```
function Greeter(greeting) {
    this.greet = function() {
        console.log(this.greeting)
    }
}

module.exports = new Greeter("Hello")
```

I would like to be able to import and use the greeter object in typescript as:

```
import Greeter from ('greeter')
Greeter.greet()
```

Which should log "Hello".

But I am unable to write a d.ts file that exports the object only the class. I try doing it like this:

```
export declare class Greeter {
    greet(): void
}
```

But when "import g from {'greeter'}" g does not have the greet method(), but has a g.Greeter class.

So how do I write a d.ts file that exports an object instance?

Answer (score 0):

To others with the same problem. The d.ts file should contain:

```
declare const _greeter: Greeeter
export default _greeter
```